# How to loop raw_input until blank entry and enforce that input is an integer?

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

I have a multiple choice input that accepts `A`, `B` or `C`.

For each scenario, a while loop is utilised to continue prompting for input until there is a blank entry, i.e. just `Enter` is pressed.

Scenario B and Scenario C are working fine.

In Scenario A, however, I want to limit the input to be an integer, and I'm having difficulties applying these two conditions ie a blank entry will exit the program and an integer is required.

So basically, pseudo code is:

- If option A is selected the input needs to be an integer which when entered will return the same prompt for an integer.  To break the loop, press `Enter`.

I'm loathe to show my attempt, but just to demonstrate the kind of things I was trying, example code is below:

```
input_01 = raw_input("Multiple Choice - Enter A, B or C :  ")
#
# when selecting A, continue to prompt for integer until input is blank
if input_01 == "A" or input_01 == "a":
        print("\nDirections for scenario A.\n")
        # BEGIN horrible attempt
        while True:
            try:
                # test if input is an integer
                a_input = int(raw_input("P1-Enter a number (blank entry to quit) :  "))
                # test if it is blank
                while a_input != "":
                        print "\nA - DONE\n"
                        print("Directions for scenario A.\n")
                        # continue to prompt for integer
                        a_input = raw_input("P2-Enter a number (blank entry to quit) :  ")
            except ValueError:
                print("\nGoing back to the first bit of A, enter a number please.\n")
        # END horrible attempt
#
# this block works as required
#
if input_01 == "B" or input_01 == "b":
        print ""
        print("Directions for scenario B.\n")
        b_input = raw_input("B - Enter anything (blank entry to quit) :  ")
        # this will keep prompting for input until blank entry
        while b_input != "":
                print "\nB - DONE\n"
                print("Directions for scenario B.\n")
                b_input = raw_input("B - Enter anything (blank entry to quit) :  ")
#
# this block works as required
#
elif input_01 == "C" or input_01 == "c":
        print ""
        print("Directions for scenario C.\n")
        c_input = raw_input("C - Enter anything (blank entry to quit) :  ")
        # this will keep prompting for input until blank entry
        while c_input != "":
                print "\nC - DONE\n"
                print("Directions for scenario C.\n")
                c_input = raw_input("C - Enter anything (blank entry to quit) :  ")
#
# this is the quit message that shown on blank entry
#
print "\nThank You, Good Bye.\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I am correct in that you just want to prompt for an integer twice...

Break out of the `while True:` loop if an exception is not caught:

```
if input_01.lower() == "a":
        print("\nDirections for scenario A.\n")
        # BEGIN horrible attempt
        while True:
            try:
                # test if input is an integer
                a_input = raw_input("P1-Enter a number (blank entry to quit) :  ")
                a_input = int(a_input)
                # This will only be executed if input is not blank
                print "\nA - DONE\n"
                print("Directions for scenario A.\n")
                        # continue to prompt for integer
                a_input = raw_input("P2-Enter a number (blank entry to quit) :  ")
                a_input = int(a_input)
            except ValueError:
                if a_input == '':
                    break
                print("\nGoing back to the first bit of A, enter a number please.\n")
```

This code will just keep repeating the loop until either input receives an empty string

Note that there a likely better ways to do what you are trying to do... but since I'm not positive what exactly you are trying to do I can just do my best to fix your code.

Comment: The behavior for scenario A should be the same as scenario B and C ie continuing to prompt until `Enter` is pressed.

Comment: I tested your solution and pressing `Enter` in `scenario A` does not have the desired effect - ie it does not quit the program.  Online interpreter of your suggestion here:   http://repl.it/6km/1

Comment: Ah yes you're right. See the edited code. Seems to work in the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a simpler approach?

```
user_choice = raw_input('Please enter A B or C: ')
while user_choice.upper() not in ('A', 'B', 'C'):
   print('Sorry, invalid entry.')
   user_choice = raw_input('Please enter A B or C: ')

if user_choice.upper() == 'A':
    print('Choice A Directions')
    user_input = raw_input('Please enter only integers, or a blank to quit: ')
    while user_input.isdigit():
       # do something with user_input, as it will be
       # overwritten
       user_input = raw_input('Please enter only integers, or a blank to quit: ')
    print('Quitting choice A, because a non-integer was entered.')
```

Note that `isdigit()` has its limitations. It won't deal nicely with fractions for example.